# Оптимизация добавления значения в массив

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, циклы, оптимизация

Ситуация следующая: допустим, у нас есть цикл, в котором на каждой итерации происходит какое-то вычисление значения. И полученное значение мы добавляем в массив на каждой итерации.

Например что-то вроде такого :

```
array = []

for i in range(1, days):
    array.append((data.query('feature_a >= @i & feature_b <= @i')['number'].sum() /\
                  data.query('feature_a >= @i & feature_b < @i')['number'].sum()))
```

И все работает, но проблема в следующем. В данной ситуации при увеличении `days`, у нас будет с каждой итерацией медленней работать код. Я так понимаю это происходит из-за постоянного добавления значения в массив. Каюсь, теоретически я не совсем понимаю почему так. Но знаю это эмпирически.

По этому вопрос следующий: есть ли возможно этого избежать, если да то какая. И отдельное спасибо если будет теоретическое объяснение почему это происходит.

Практическая задача для понимания что хочется получить и что сделать:

У нас есть примерно такой вот DataFrame:

[image: Пример DataFrame'a]

Нам нужно получить с этих данные отношение суммы платежей всех игроков, чей `lifetime` не меньше N, а `paydar` не больше N, к сумме платежей всех игроков, чей `lifetime` не меньше N а `paydar` меньше N.

В целом это получается что-то вроде метрики: SumRev_N / SumRev_N-1

Это можно получить кодом выше, заменив необходимые наименование. То есть

```
array = []

for i in range(1, days):
    array.append((data.query('lifetime >= @i & paydar <= @i')['payment'].sum() /\
                  data.query('lifetime >= @i & paydar < @i')['payment'].sum()))
```

Comment: скорее всего можно избежать циклов, т.к. в pandas они практически не нужны. объясните, что вы пытаетесь сделать и что получить в итоге, с воспроизводимым примером данных.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже думал сделать без цикла, но так и не придумал решение. Описал в вопросе что и зачем хочу получить в итоге

Comment: у вас *N* постоянно меняется?

Comment: Всё верно, N меняется постоянно. В цикле это i. Например нам нужно собрать эту метрику для 300 дней. Тогда тут N будет принимать значение от 1 до 300

Answer (score 1):

На больших данных лучше всего использовать векторные вычисления.
Для этого есть прекрасная библиотека ***NumPy***

Вообще я бы изначально, зная границы цикла, отсекал бы по ним часть датафрейма.
(в этом коде ваш изначальный датафрейм *data* - это *df2*)

```
low, hight = 1, 300 #границы цикла
```

Отсекаем df по условию. Для отсечения достаточно включить одно ваше условие, потому что второе в него входит.

```
def condit(x, y):
    df_of = df2[((df2.lifetime >= x) | (df2.paydar <= x)) & ((df2.lifetime >= y) & (df2.paydar <= y))]
    return df_of
```

Отсеченный фрейм:

```
df = condit(low, hight)
```

Создадим функцию вашего изначального цикла (как оказалось, без него не обойтись :) )

```
def div_elems(x):
    increasing = np.sum(np.where((df['lifetime'].values >= x) & (df['paydar'].values <= x), df['payment'].values, 0))
    strictly = np.sum(np.where((df['lifetime'].values >= x) & (df['paydar'].values < x), df['payment'].values, 0))
    return np.true_divide(increasing, strictly)
```

Получаем ваш список:

```
your_list = [div_elems(i) for i in np.arange(low, hight)]
```

***P.S.***
Изначально прикидывал *без отсечения*, скорость с *NumPy*, в отличии от Вашего цикла была от 2 до 4 раз выше, в зависимости от размера.
Сейчас же будет еще быстрее.